# Function to get data keep running in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that gets some data from my backend and then I want simply to assign it to the state and display it in my browser. Everything works correctly, but I don't know why when I run a request the function keeps calling the API without stopping. What is the reason for this?
It seems that the function is stuck in some kind of while-true loop.

```
function App() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState();

  const getOrders = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");
    setOrders(response);
    console.log(response);
  };
  getOrders();
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(orders)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

[image: multiple calls to the backend]

Comment: I would suggest adding a `debugger;` above `const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");` and inspect the call stack in a debugging environment.

Comment: You start rendering the component and also create an async request which will resolve some time later. The render completes and some time later your async request completes. This will trigger a rerender which will in turn create a new async request and so on ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the reason for this?

This happens because you are calling a function every render inside the functional component.

```
  const getOrders = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");
    setOrders(response); // this will re render the component
    console.log(response);
  };
  getOrders(); // this will be called every render and cause the infinity loop
```

When you render the component, you call `getOrders` and this functions calls `setOrders` wich will rerender the component, causing a infinity loop.

---

First render => call `getOrders` => call `setOrders` => Rerender =>

Second render => call `getOrders` => call `setOrders` => Rerender =>
...

---

You need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook or call the function on some event (maybe button click)

e.g. using `useEffect`

```
function App() {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getOrders = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");
            setOrders(response);
            console.log(response);
        };
       getOrders();
    }, []); 

    return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(orders)}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Effect hook React offers:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
function App() {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState();

    const getOrders = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");
        setOrders(response);
        console.log(response);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
       getOrders();
    }, []); //Empty array = no dependencies = acts like componentDidMount / will only run once

    return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(orders)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using react-hooks here, so your getOrders function is getting render all the time.

Use useEffect from react to avoid this.

```
    function App() {
      const [orders, setOrders] = useState();

      useEffect(() => {
const getOrders = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/orders/");
        setOrders(response);
        console.log(response);
      };
      getOrders();
}, [])
      return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(orders)}</div>;
    }

    export default App;
```